# Can a VHDL configuration have generics of it's own?

Tags: tcl, vhdl, modelsim

**What I want to do:**

I want to pass the current date and time to a VHDL testbench so I can create nicer report file names.

**The Problem:**

The Top level VHDL file that is being called from my simulation TCL scripts is a configuration and I don't know how to pass the genericto it. The interesing part of the TCL script is the following:

```
set reportfilename "report_$testcase_id"
append reportfilename [clock format [clock seconds] -format _%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M]
vsim -t 10fs -gG_TC_REPORTFILE=$reportfilename -novopt work.CFG_TB_TOP_tc0027 - wlf result_$testcase_id.wlf
```

The resulting VSIM call looks like this:

```
# vsim -t 10fs -wlf result_tc0027.wlf -novopt -gG_TC_REPORTFILE=report_tc0027_2014-03-05_13:22 work.CFG_TB_TOP_tc0027
```

The problem is that G_TC_REPORTFILE is not a generic of CFG_TB_TOP_tc0027.vhd, but of one of the modules configured IN CFG_TB_TOP_tc0027.vhd

The relevant part of CFG_TB_TOP_tc0027.vhd:

```
configuration CFG_TB_TOP_tc0027 of TB_TOP_CFG is
   for testcaseexecution
      for TB_TOP_E_INST : TB_TOP_E
         -------------------------------------------------------------
         -- Testbench configuration
         -------------------------------------------------------------

         use entity work.TB_TOP_E(TB_TOP_sim)
            generic map (
               G_TC_STIMULUSFILE => "./testcases/tc0027.txt",  -- 
               G_TC_REPORTFILE   => "./results/report_tc0027.txt",
               G_TB_VNR          => "V_03.10",
               G_TC_NR           => 27);    -- 

         for TB_TOP_A_sim
```

How would I pass the value from the TCL file to the generic G_TC_REPORTFILE of the TB_TOP_E entity? Can I somehow add a generic to the CFG file, or can I somehow specify for which entity the generic in the TCL file is meant? Best-case-scenario would be if I would not have to edit the vhdl files, only the TCL scripts.

The simulator is ModelSim SE 10.0b, I'm using VHDL 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found the answer myself:

You can indeed specify a path to the generic you want to overwrite. I changed the TCL file like this:

```
set reportfilename "./results/report_$testcase_id"
append reportfilename [clock format [clock seconds] -format _%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M.txt]
vsim -t 10fs -GTB_TOP_CFG/TB_TOP_E_INST/G_TC_REPORTFILE=$reportfilename -novopt work.CFG_TB_TOP_tc0027 -wlf result_$testcase_id.wlf
```

Which produces the following VSIM call:

```
# vsim -t 10fs -wlf result_tc0027.wlf -novopt -GTB_TOP_CFG/TB_TOP_E_INST/G_TC_REPORTFILE=./results/report_tc0027_2014-03-05_14-06.txt work.CFG_TB_TOP_tc0027
```

In addition to adding the path `TB_TOP_CFG/TP_TOP_E_INST/` I also had to remove the `:` from the timestamp, as modelsim/vhdl did not handle it.